# If $f_n: [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are RCLL (i.e. càdlàg) with bounded $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f_n$, then $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n$ is RCLL

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

Assume we have a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of RCLL (i.e. càdlàg, i.e. right-continuous admitting left limits) functions $f_n : [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the property that, for every $x \in [0,T]$ there exists $K > 0$ with $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|f_n(x)| \leq K$. So we can define a function $f^*(x):=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f_n(x)$ for every $x \in [0,T]$ and see that $f^*:[0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ .

My **question** now is, wheter we can say that $f^*$ is RCLL (i.e. càdlàg), since I cannot think of a counterexample, and cannot come up with a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x\leq0 \\
nx & x\leq1/n \\
1 & x\geq1/n
\end{cases}
$$
are continuous, hence RCLL, but
$$
f(x) = \sup_{n} f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x\leq0 \\
1 & x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
is not right continuous.